# [Eclipse not starting]:An error has occured. See the log file null

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm unable to get my Eclipse Luna running. It was working fine till now and suddenly crashed. Now when i try to start it, I get the error saying:

**An error has occured. See the log file null**

I tried **launching eclipse from terminal** and also tried to **delete the metadata folder from my workspace** but nothing helped me.

Here is the crash log:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error initializing container.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:93)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:209)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:201)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:168)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.initWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:137)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:83)
... 12 more

Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: setSeed() failed
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:458)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$300(NativePRNG.java:329)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:212)
at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:209)
at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:190)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.computeNodeAddress(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:127)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.UniversalUniqueIdentifier.<clinit>(UniversalUniqueIdentifier.java:35)
... 14 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:313)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implSetSeed(NativePRNG.java:456)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Check for any permission errors or disk being full.

Comment: @KalyanChavali I don't see any permissions for eclipse. Is there any that we have to set explicitly for eclipse? I'm using mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using Solaris? This OS has an alternative entropy source called EGD, which needs special protocol to write to, which Sun JDK does not implement...

Can you try adding `-Djava.security.egd=/dev/random` to the `vmargs` section of your `eclipse.ini`.

If you still see the same issue. Make sure your user can write to `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Few files in my security folder **/jre/lib/security** had got messed up. 
Downloaded latest Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) and put the jars (**Download US_export_policy.jar** and **local_policy.jar**) in the security folder. My eclipse works fine now.